# Freezer not freezing, fridge works fine

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Frigidaire side by side unit that is just around 2 years old. Yesterday evening we noticed the freezer side was cold but the food was thawing. Took everything out and put in a chest freezer. Today we checked for dust on coils, ice froze on interior components, door seal problems....everything seemed fine. The compressor seems to be constantly kicking on and off and sounds alot louder than usual, but the fridge is working just fine....still maintaining it's temperature and cold as usual. I was thinking if the compressor was the problem we would be experiencing fridge problems, too? I also keep reading that the fridge gets it's cold air from the freezer so if the freezer isn't working then the fridge won't run properly either, but that's not the case here. Suggestions on what the problem may be?

Comment: Possibly related: [Freezer too warm - thermostat or leak?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/86250/23448)

Comment: Ice in a bit that's not really accessible, blocking circulation? You could try defrosting for several days if you have an alternative fridge.

Comment: A Low freon charge can cause the evaporator to be cool but not cold enough to freeze. If the coils are clean the next check is to verify there is not an air blockage at the bottom of the freezer, water frozen on the bottom can block the air flow and this can happen from the door not being fully shut for several hours. If everything is clear it probably has a slow leak and will need a recharge and the leak sealed. This is not a normal DIY repair because of EPA licensing required.

Comment: Is there a light in the freezer?  If so, check that it isn't staying on when the door is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Mine has an air channel between the two compartments that can freeze up (it happens if someone fails to close the door fully, leading to excess humidity).  Then, everything goes haywire.  Worse, the ice is invisible until it really builds up.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same brand and it is a PITA. It needs to keep the air moving inside the case. If the air does not circulate it will create the problem you have. There is in ours, a charcoal filter that needs to be changed every 6 months, otherwise it restricts the airflow. Items inside the fridge part needs to be away from the back wall and the filter so air moves.

The logic is, yes the fridge part is cold enough, the struggling freezer part can maintain the 38 or so degrees to keep the fridge proper, but without circulation, the freezer can't do what it needs to get down to 0 degrees.

If yours has a charcoal filter remove it and the temp should return to normal. It will cause no harm, I had to do it myself and I ordered filters online to replace it.